# about Random Variables Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

suppose $\mathcal{G} \space is \space \mathcal{F}'s \space sub \space \sigma-algebra, and \space X\in\mathcal{L^1}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P), \space\ $$\ Y\in\mathcal{L^1}(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)\ .$

If$$E(X;G)=E(Y;G)$$ holds for each $G$ in a $\pi-system$ which contains $\Omega$ and generates $\mathcal{G}$, prove the equation also holds for each $G \in \mathcal{G}$

Comment: I think I should use the uniqueness of extension of $\pi$-system, but I don't know whether I am wrong and how to write it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate application of Dynkin's $\pi -\lambda$ theorem. See Billingsley's Probability and Measure for a proof of this theorem.

Comment: here is my maybe-right solution: just think about $P(X-Y)^+$ and knows that it is a measure on the $\pi$-system and it can be uniquely extended to $\mathcal{G}$. And I also learned countalbe union of zero-measured sets are also zero-measured , so I can know $P(X-Y)$ is zero on $\mathcal{G}$